# Vim 8 :helptags not working

Tags: vim

As an example, I cloned `https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git` into `~/vimfiles/pack/default/opt` (I'm on Windows). This created the plugin folder structure and I'm able to load the solarized colorscheme with `:colorscheme solarized`.

Now I want to generate helptags, so I run `:helptags ~/vimfiles/pack/default/opt/vim-colors-solarized/doc/`. No feedback, either success or failure. Then I try typing `:h solarized` and get the error `E149: sorry, no help for solarized`.

I looked at the tags file in the docs folder, and while I am unfamiliar with the file's conventions, it clearly looks like there should be a tag for `solarized`.

What have I done wrong, or what can I try to do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [princker in /r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/87v6lz/vim_8_helptags_not_working/dwfw7yv/)

Apparently you must add optional packages with `:packadd` prior to generating helptags. In fact, later experience leads me to believe that simply executing `:packadd` is sufficient to also generate helptags. This problem does not occur for packages placed in the `startup` folder of a package.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and, for example, `:helptags $HOME\vimfiles\pack\layout\opt\SimpylFold` has no effect. I have to `:helptags ALL`, which is slow, and  throws errors about the `C:\Program Files\...` tags (because that's not writeable). This is a bug.

Comment: (but in the light of [filbranden's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20810/how-to-load-vim8-optional-packages-in-vimrc), I quit using opt directories)